# Office suite on Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

What can I use to view office documents on the Ubuntu phone? I would like to be able to view odf and ms office documents like doc and docx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [document viewer](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.docviewer) app now shows **all formats that are compatible with LibreOffice**. These inlcude odf, doc, docx, ppt, pptx and many more.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, Ubuntu phone has the capability to run X.org applications on Mir (the display server that it uses) via Xmir. However, [there aren't any officially supported applications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Which_applications_do_run_on_Ubuntu_Touch.3F).

However, this isn't perfect because Mir and X.org are different beasts, and so not all X.org applications will be able to be run with Xmir right away because of the amount of work it would take to port them.

That said, LibreOffice [would appear to be an application that was successfully working on Xmir](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+WillCooke/posts/eNUArFBzh3W).

However, there is still no mobile-optimized application for doing this on Ubuntu Mobile, so I'm not sure how useful running straight LibreOffice would be on Ubuntu Mobile because of scaling and just having the UI not meant to be used on such a small screen.

Basically your best bet would be to use [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/) or Microsoft Office 365, since those are web-based applications and can be used on mobile.

Something to note on your way out, LibreOffice is currently beng ported (in beta still) [to Android](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Android). So, I'm guessing there will be an Ubuntu Mobile port in the not too distant future.