# How to open a docx file on Ubuntu phone

Tags: installed-programs

Is it possible to open up a docx file on my Ubuntu phone? Is there an app I can install?

Thanks,
Naomi

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening it in [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) or another online application.  There isn't any official office app for the Ubuntu phone yet.

Edit:
I just ran across this answer to a related question - So take heart, it may be coming soon...
[Office suite on Ubuntu Phone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604412/office-suite-on-ubuntu-phone?lq=1)